# Getting method range of object _worksheet failed for the below code

Tags: vba, excel, range

**My code**

```
Set myRange1 = ws1.Range("B5", ws1.Range("B5" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: if you want to keep getting help here, you should give people here that helped you some positive feedbacks , you can start by marking as "answer" (or up-voting in other scenarios)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the range from Cell "B5" untill the last row with data in Column B (with skipping blank cells in the middle) use the code below :

```
With ws1
    Set myRange1 = .Range("B5:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

**Option 2**: If you are trying to get the range from Cell "B5" untill the last row with data in Column B (without skipping blank cells in the middle) use this optional code below :

```
With ws1
    Set myRange1 = .Range("B5:B" & .Range("B5").End(xlDown).Row)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following part is strange.

```
ws1.Range("B5" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

"B5" & Rows.Count is not correct.

If you wont use Rows.Count.
Try this.

```
ws1.Range("B" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
```